# jalv equalizer (eq10q) mutes sound when running (among other errors)

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, jack

I'm trying to use a sound [equalizer](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=all&keywords=equalizer) in Debian Jessie. I already have pulseaudio installed, so I thought about `pulseaudio-equalizer`, but it seems it's only available for Debian Stretch. So I'm trying `eq10q`, which made me install lots of other libraries (like libgtkmm-2.4-dev, lv2-dev, jalv, jack, qjackctl, pulseaudio-module-jack...). Still it doesn't work as I think it should. If I run

```
jalv.gtk http://eq10q.sourceforge.net/eq/eq10qs
```

I got a long error message (copied in the end of this question), and the program halts (any music playing freezes for about one second).

If I run `jalv.gtk3` instead of `jalv.gtk`, I get a somewhat ugly interface, but there's no sound (Videos won't even play a song, VLC plays the song, but I get no sound). After closing the jalv.gtk3 window the sound reappears, Videos start playing. The same happens with `jalv.gtkmm` (with the only difference of a beautiful interface).

I already killed pulseaudio, started and stopped jack_control, restarted pulseaudio (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/557908/416671)), rebooted the computer, nothing works.

This is the error message I got:

```
rodrigo@debian:~$ jalv.gtk http://eq10q.sourceforge.net/eq/eq10qs
Plugin:       http://eq10q.sourceforge.net/eq/eq10qs
UI:           http://eq10q.sourceforge.net/eq/eq10qs/gui
JACK Name:    EQ10Q Stereo
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2014 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:PCH,0|hw:PCH,0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 48000Hz, period = 1024 frames (21.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Block length: 1024 frames
MIDI buffers: 32768 bytes
Comm buffers: 524288 bytes
Update rate:  25.0 Hz

bypass          = 0.000000
input_gain      = 0.000000
output_gain     = 0.000000
filter1_gain    = 0.000000
filter2_gain    = 0.000000
filter3_gain    = 0.000000
filter4_gain    = 0.000000
filter5_gain    = 0.000000
filter6_gain    = 0.000000
filter7_gain    = 0.000000
filter8_gain    = 0.000000
filter9_gain    = 0.000000
filter10_gain   = 0.000000
filter1_freq    = 30.000000
filter2_freq    = 60.000000
filter3_freq    = 120.000000
filter4_freq    = 240.000000
filter5_freq    = 480.000000
filter6_freq    = 960.000000
filter7_freq    = 1920.000000
filter8_freq    = 3840.000000
filter9_freq    = 7680.000000
filter10_freq   = 15360.000000
filter1_q       = 0.700000
filter2_q       = 0.700000
filter3_q       = 2.000000
filter4_q       = 2.000000
filter5_q       = 2.000000
filter6_q       = 2.000000
filter7_q       = 2.000000
filter8_q       = 2.000000
filter9_q       = 0.700000
filter10_q      = 0.700000
filter1_type    = 6.000000
filter2_type    = 9.000000
filter3_type    = 11.000000
filter4_type    = 11.000000
filter5_type    = 11.000000
filter6_type    = 11.000000
filter7_type    = 11.000000
filter8_type    = 11.000000
filter9_type    = 10.000000
filter10_type   = 2.000000
filter1_enable  = 0.000000
filter2_enable  = 0.000000
filter3_enable  = 0.000000
filter4_enable  = 0.000000
filter5_enable  = 0.000000
filter6_enable  = 0.000000
filter7_enable  = 0.000000
filter8_enable  = 0.000000
filter9_enable  = 0.000000
filter10_enable = 0.000000
in_1_vu_ctl     = 0.000000
in_2_vu_ctl     = 0.000000
out_2_vu_ctl    = 0.000000
out_2_vu_ctl    = 0.000000

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): glibmm-CRITICAL **: Glib::ObjectBase* Glib::wrap_create_new_wrapper(GObject*): assertion 'wrap_func_table != 0' failed

(jalv.gtk:4065): glibmm-WARNING **: Failed to wrap object of type 'GdkPixbuf'. Hint: this error is commonly caused by failing to call a library init() function.
Segmentation fault
rodrigo@debian:~$ Unknown error...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Jack::JackTemporaryException'
  what():
```

The error message ends abruptly with this `what():`. I imagine that I should be able to hear the sound as I move the controls in the equalizer, right?

Answer (score 1):

Sound on Linux is a bit of a mess, so here's some background: ALSA is the basic soundsystem that both provides the hardware drivers in the kernel, and ways to configure and access them. On top of that, there's Pulseaudio (which is what most distributions today use as default), which allows more convenient and flexible sound sources and sinks, including networking stuff, and Jack, which was made for low latency transport, depends on a single sound card for the timing, and is intended for (semi-)professional recording and mixing tasks.

The last two are really *alternatives*, and don't work well together. You said you have installed Pulseaudio, but from the error messages

```
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
```

etc., `jalv` is using Jack. This won't work.

So you need to use a different equalizer for Pulseaudio. I haven't used an equalizer for Pulseaudio (and I don't want to :-), so I can't give recommendations.